# asp.net MVC - using list of strings in a DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to use Html.DropDownListFor with the list of strings from a ViewBag.

Basically I got a ViewBag with a list of string like "Adam","Tom","Mike" etc...

I was wandering if it is possible to pass this list in to DropDownListFor where both Value and text are the items from my list.

I wasn't able to use foreach here...

example with hardcode:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, new SelectList(
          new List<Object>{

               new { value = "Adam" , text = "Adam"  },
               new { value = "Tom" , text = "Tom"  },
               new { value = "Mike" , text = "Mike"  },
               new { value = "Jake" , text = "Jake"  },
            },
          "value",
          "text",
           2))
```

Comment: The problem with `List<Object>` is that you can't ever reference the properties of each (Object)item `value` and `text`. Map these to a list of `SelectListItem`.

Comment: Have you tried passing that list of strings to the [first overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a collection of `SelectListItem`s from the list of strings and use that with `DropDownListFor` helper method.

```
var names = new List<string> {"Adam", "Sam"};
ViewBag.Names = names.Select(f => new SelectListItem() {Value = f, Text = f});
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(f=>f.Name, ViewBag.Names as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
                                                                    "select one")
```