# Using a simple List with @html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have been trying to figure out how to get the syntax correct so I can load a drop down list with a simple list of string in MVC.

What is the correct format?

The following code

```
@Html.DropDownList("VMO", List<string>(ViewBag.VMOList), new { @class = "form-control SearchCriteria", id = "VMO", name = "VMO", multiple = "multiple"})
```

gives me error

```
"Non-invocable member 'List<T> cannot be used like a method.
```

Comment: `List<string>(ViewBag.VMOList)` is probably the problem. Change to, `new SelectList(ViewBag.VMOList)`. Not sure that will work though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net MVC - using list of strings in a DropDownListFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133989/asp-net-mvc-using-list-of-strings-in-a-dropdownlistfor)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a `Select List` with `list of string` using `@Html.DropDownList()` then it should be as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("VMO", new SelectlIst(ViewBag.VMOList),"Select Item", new { @class = "form-control SearchCriteria", id = "VMO", name = "VMO", multiple = "multiple"})
```

Or If you want to make a `Select List` with `list of object` using `@Html.DropDownList()` then it should be as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("VMO", new SelectlIst(ViewBag.VMOList,"ObjectId","ObjectName"),"Select Item", new { @class = "form-control SearchCriteria", id = "VMO", name = "VMO", multiple = "multiple"})
```